# PowerShell Digits

Tags: powershell, export

Trying to export current temperature from the XML to a text file.  The results are are "xx.y" but I only need xx exported to the text file.  I've tried several commands but keep striking out.  Any ideas?

([xml](Invoke-WebRequest -URI http://w1.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KSJC.xml).Content).current_observation.temp_f | Out-File c:\temperature.txt

Answer (score 0):

i suspect i am misunderstanding something [this seems alarmingly simple], but here are a few ways to do what it seems you want ... [*grin*]

```
$Temperature = '12.3'

$Temperature.Split('.')[0]
[int]$Temperature
[math]::Round([decimal]$Temperature, 0)
```

the output if each is `12`.

- the 1st uses the string `.Split()` method and takes the 1st item in the resulting array
- the 2nd uses the `[int]` type accelerator to coerce the string into an int & rounds it in the process
- the 3rd uses the `[decimal]` type accelerator to coerce the string to a decimal number and the `[math]::Round()` static method to round the number to 0 decimal places

Comment: To add to this: `[Math]::Floor($Temperature)` and `[Math]::Truncate($Temperature)` will round down. `[Math]::Ceiling($Temperature)` will round up. `[Math]::Round($Temperature, [System.MidpointRounding]::ToEven)` when a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward the nearest even number. `[Math]::Round($Temperature, [System.MidpointRounding]::AwayFromZero)` when a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward the nearest number that is away from zero. See [MidpointRounding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @Theo - ooo ... neato! i had forgotten about the floor/truncate variants. thanks for the reminder ... [*grin*]

Comment: Just thought I'd mention it. So much you can do with numbers... ;)

Comment: it's much appreciated ... [*grin*]